# Invalid Location at glUniform() trying to do Point Shadows

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shadow

I'm trying to do point shadowing in an Engine I'm doing (following [Learn OpenGL tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Shadows/Point-Shadows)) and I'm a bit stucked in a point in which I'm trying to pass a uniform to a geometry shader, by doing the next:

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(points_shadowsShader->ID, std::string("shadowMatrices[" + std::to_string(i) + "]").c_str()), 1, GL_FALSE, shadowTransforms[i].ptr());
```

Being the uniform in geometry shader `uniform mat4 shadowMatrices[6]`. This gives me location -1, but also, with a simple uniform in the fragment shader `uniform vec3 lightPos`, gives me location -1. However, when passing the model matrix uniform to the vertex shader with the same technique (a line down from this code), it gets correctly the uniform (location 3).

I've been debugging and the shader is compiling properly (passing through the error-retrieval opengl's functions, is giving me OK in Vertex, Fragment and Geometry shader compilations and linkage), and also, looking at the shader code I store, the uniforms are there, so I can't see why is giving me location -1. Does somebody has some advice at looking into this problem?

The vertex shader is a simple vertex shader:

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 a_Position;

uniform mat4 u_Proj;
uniform mat4 u_View;
uniform mat4 u_Model;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = u_Proj * u_View * u_Model * vec4(a_Position, 1.0);
}
```

The geometry shader is the same than the one shown in the tutorial:

```
layout (triangles) in; 
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices = 18) out;     

uniform mat4 shadowMatrices[6];
out vec4 FragPos;   

void main()
{ 
    for (int face = 0; face < 6; ++face) 
    {
        gl_Layer = face;
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        {
            FragPos = gl_in[i].gl_Position;
            gl_Position = shadowMatrices[face] * FragPos;
            EmitVertex();
        }    
        EndPrimitive();
    }
}
```

And the fragment shader is pretty simple too, as in the tutorial:

```
uniform vec3 lightPos = vec3(0.0, 5.0, 0.0);
in vec4 FragPos;

void main()
{
    float lightDistance = length(FragPos.xyz - lightPos);
    lightDistance = lightDistance / 1000.0;
    gl_FragDepth = lightDistance;
}
```

To pass the uniforms (explained very briefly), I just bind this shader (glUseProgram), iterate all meshes I have to draw and pass the uniforms and make a draw call.

Comment: I had into account if the uniform was active or not, and they are actually used, so they should

Comment: I typically query for uniform locations by name and build a `std::map`. Anything that's not found gets a map value of -1, and the render engine just ignores those. There's a bit of overhead up front, but it's a very flexible approach. In ~15 years, I haven't used `layout(location)` and I think that has helped me preserve what remains of my sanity.

Comment: Hahah yes, that's cool, actually, I also had kind of a "cache" system for uniforms, but in this case, I can't do that because of how the code is done... And also because the problem of my question would still be there, right?